# Dockerizing Nodejs APP (graceful restart, ssl)

Tags: node.js, express, ssl, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to dockerize a NodeJS application. I have followed this tutorial https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/

It is really easy and works.

But I need extend functionality a little bit.

My infrastructure won't contain only the nodejs container, it will have much more containers that are linked together with the help of `docker-compose` file.

What I need

1. I am going to use `https` for my application. So I need to provide my SSL certificates in folder that will be mount to a host machine. But I guess I need to restart an express app in order to apply changes. How can I handle this use case ? In case I have other containers running.
2. I need to be able to restart nodejs app without restarting a container.

Could you please suggest the right strategy to follow in order implement this properly ?

Comment: 1) is not a good idea, put a frontal reverse proxy like Caddy (https://caddyserver.com) or Traefik (https://traefik.io) to handle SSL stuff in front of all your containers.

Comment: 2) is not possible because in idiomatic docker containers, container lifetime is linked to process lifetime, in your case, the node.js process

Comment: @papey thanks for the answer, do these services work in the same way as Haproxy works with SSL termination ?